# How can I use TDD (tests first) for password hashing implementation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, language-agnostic, hash, tdd

I have a bit of a paradox.

I'm trying to use TDD to build tests for my password hashing methods before I build the implementation.  But I don't how to come up with the expected values beforehand, without first building the implementation.

Of course, with simple hashing implementation, I can probably find a site to create the expected values based on the known password/salt.

I'm betting the solution is to make an exception for TDD and forgo building my tests first.  Rather, build my implementation to come up with the proper salt/hash values, then build my tests against those values to prevent regression.

But I thought I would post this to see if there's a solution I'm not thinking of.

Or, maybe there's someone out there that can generate hashes in their head in order to build the tests first.

Comment: Are you going to invent a new hashing algorithm? If not, there is supposedly "prior art" that you can use to calculate some these data.

Comment: Many things go into hashing a password.  For example, many people use: some random generated value stored w/ user + some static compiled literal value + password.  Then, when using RFC2898, the hash can change based on the number of iterations.  If any of these variables ever change, the authentication will break (and thus, the unit tests should too).

Comment: If you can't write the tests first, how can you ever know that you wrote your code correctly? Are you just going to accept that "correct" means "whatever the first version of this algorithm produces"? Isn't there some other standard of correctness here you can use to write tests?

Comment: When would you say you've solved the problem? The tests are just an executable rephrasing of 'what needs to be done.' So specs like the function should produce unique hashes for a set of n inputs & run within 0.5 secs can be written as an automated test to start things off... How you do it is 'internals' and can be tweaked to taste as long as the tests do not break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know if you are writing your own hashing function, like sha-1 (in this case just don't do it) or you are using external hash and random functions to generate salt etc. in second case you don't have to know your output. you just can mock your hash and random providers and check if they are called on your input and or partial results

Comment: This is actually the approach I ended up going with, and just never followed up.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you should know "expected" output when you are doing TDD. In your case expected output is the results of hashing function.

If you are implementing known hashing algorigm, it's not a problem to take an tests results from either their sites or just produce them manually.

In case you are developing own algorithm. You should also probably know the expected output by implementing prototype of algorithm implementation. Even if you don't know are they right or not, you just making an assumption they right and use values in tests. If the implementation of hash function is changed, those tests become red.